# Interpreting ipmitool ser list memory errors

Tags: memory, ipmitool

I'm purchasing some second hand servers, which the seller has given me remote access to. Running `ipmitool [..] ser list`, they seem clean other than these repeated a few months ago on each:

```
 [..] | System Firmware Error | Unspecified | Asserted
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 11 DIMM 1
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 11 DIMM 1
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 3 DIMM 1
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 11 DIMM 1
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 11 DIMM 1
 [..] | Memory | Configuration Error | Asserted | CPU 3 DIMM 1
```

I'm completely new to using ipmi. From a daily usage perspective, should the presence of these errors be concerning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ipmi spec version 1.5](https://extras.csc.fi/mgrid/docs/IPMI_v1.5_spec.pdf) in page 375 (about sensor 0x0C/0X07):

> Configuration error. Indicates a memory configuration error for the
>   entity associated with the sensor. This can include when a given
>   implementation of the entity is not supported by the system (e.g.,
>   when the particular size of the memory module is unsupported) or that
>   the entity is part of an unsupported memory configuration (e.g. the
>   configuration is not supported because the memory module doesn’t match
>   other memory modules)

from that you can understand that this is not a critical issue and just means someone put incorrect DIMMs in the server. This was probably corrected later.

Comment: This was exactly the issue, and was corroborated by the seller. Much appreciated, thank you :).